# No profile page member found matching the query: Profile page of all users (except admin) does not render)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am continuing my Django journey and again turn to this forum for guidance.

**Problem definition**

Whenever I sign in into the website (I've successfully implemented CVB user authentication) with none-admin users, the encounter this error:

[image]

**What I have done**

- I've made sure that the database is not empty; there are plenty of objects to query.
- I've tried to read the Django documentation on CBV and tried to understand all the different methods of the CB-DetailView and query the database.

**Project setup**:

In my project, I have several apps such as a main app for general functions, authentication app, profilepage app, settings app etc. The issue that I have concerns the profile_app I believe.

**My question**

1. How do I render the profile page of a specific user? I not familiar with how dynamic filtering using slug/Pk works when using CBV. I believe that DetailView is the right generic view that I'm using.
2. What changes do I have to do solve this error described above?

**Model 1 - From app:  main_app**

```
class Member(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):

    # Fields for sign up page
    username = models.CharField(
        _("Användarnamn"), max_length=50, unique=True, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(
        _("Mail"), max_length=100, unique=True, default='')
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Ålder"), null=True, blank=False)
    country = models.CharField(_("Land"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    county = models.CharField(_("Län"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_("Stad"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    sex = models.CharField(_("Kön"), max_length=50,
                           null=True, blank=True, choices=sex_choices)
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        _("Profilbild"), upload_to="static/user_profile_pics", null=True, blank=True)
    account_created = models.DateTimeField(
        _("Medlem sedan"), null=True, auto_created=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(
        _("Senast inloggad"), null=True, auto_now=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    count = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

**Model 2 - From app:  profile_app**

```
class ProfilePageMember(models.Model):
    members = models.OneToOneField(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    education = models.CharField(
        _("Utbildning"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, choices=education)
    count = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.members)
```

**Profile_app - View**

```
from typing import Any
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.http import request
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from profile_app.forms import *
from profile_app.models import *
from messages_app.models import Message

user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
# Create your views here.

# Redirect to user profile from the navbar


class ProfilePageView(DetailView):
    model = ProfilePageMember
    template_name = "profile_app/profilepage.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["user_data"] = ProfilePageMember.objects.all()
        return context
```

**Profile_app - URL**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "profilepage_app"

urlpatterns = [
    path("profilsida/<int:pk>/",
         views.ProfilePageView.as_view(), name="profile-redirect"),
]
```

Comment: I see 2 problems. In your ProfilePageView nothing is returned, the url definition of the view expected a parameter pk (primary key) that is int and not str. So, first fix you url ...'profilsida/<int:pk>'... after pass the pk parameter to the ProfilePageView like: return render(request, 'profile_app/profilepage.html', {'pk': request.user})

Comment: I did try this but it didn't work. Also, I tried using get_context_data to render the data from my model but I get the same error :(

I've updated the view, you can see the code above.

Comment: Post your profilepage.html to see how you're passing the context. In fact you need to add one more path (like /users) in your urls.py, because 'profilsida/<int:pk>' is used to show/edit one record, but you are passing a queryset (ProfilePageMember.objects.all()) to context.